# Where to install Redis certificate

Tags: java, spring-boot, redis, certificate

I have a certificate for Redis.  Where do I install this certificate to connect to my Redis server?

I've tried to throw it into my java cacerts, but it doesn't work.

What is the proper way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I've also been trying to connect a Java app with Jedis 3.5.0 to a Redis cluster (6.10.0).

1. **Build Redis with SSL**

First of all, the redis binary must be built with the BUILD_TLS=yes flag as per https://redis.io/topics/encryption (if you are hosting yourself)

2. **creating the redis_key_store**

Will have to generate a redis.crt file to connect to redis and a redis-ca.crt file to verify the identity of your node/cluster.
Or you can use the files generate by "./runtest --tls" in  ./tests/tls.

Create a p12 key store :

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -in redis.crt -inkey redis.key -out redis_key_store.p12 -passout pass:keystore_pwd
```

and save the resulting redis_key_store.p12 somewhere safe.

3. **add the Redis instance to your trusted sources**

find your trustStore and copy the redis-ca.crt and redis-ca.key files next to it.

Add the redis-ca to the trustStore :

```
keytool -import -file redis-ca.crt -alias redis-ca -keystore truststore.jks -storepass truststore_pwd
```

4. **start your redis node/cluster**
   you must change/add to the configuration of the redis nodes the location of the certificates as per

https://redis.io/topics/encryption#certificate-configuration

5. **Create a simple class to test the connection**

Then I created a class like in step 3 from [this page](https://redislabs.com/blog/enabling-secure-connections-to-redis-enterprise/)

```
public class SSLTest
{
    private static final String HOSTNAME = "localhost";
    private static final int PORT = 6379;

    public static void main (String[] args) {

        try {
            System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStoreType", "PKCS12");
            System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", "path/to/cert/redis_key_store.p12");
            System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", "keystore_pwd");
            System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStoreType", "JKS");
            System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "path/to/cert/truststore.jks");
            System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", "truststore_pwd");

            Jedis jedis = new Jedis(HOSTNAME, PORT, true);
            jedis.connect();
            jedis.auth("redacted");

            System.out.println(jedis.ping());

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

==> The code should print out "PONG"